# How make variables global if it call from script and on server side in R?

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables

Let see the following example.

There are 2 files: "setting.R" with the name of app and window title, and "app.R" that works as a web app. I have to call "settings.R" on server side during loading application (only in this way). Unfortunately, variables in "settings.R" are not global, and I get error in shiny-server log "Error in navbarPage(app_name ... object 'app_name' not found". Using "<<-" operator for 'app_name <<- "Test App"' not helps.

The code running in "settings.R" depends on the parameter "app_id" that defined on server side. So, I can't use "global.R" also.

The question is how to make "app_name" and "window_title" variables global or visible in any other way in "app.R".

```
settings.R
=====
if(app_id == "1") {
  app_name <- "App 1"
  window_title <- "Title 1"
}

if(app_id == "2") {
  app_name <- "App 2"
  window_title <- "Title 2"
}

app.R
=====   

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {      
  output$uo_init_app <- renderUI({
    app_id <- "1"        
    source("settings.R")        
  })      
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
   navbarPage(app_name, 
              windowTitle = window_title, 
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_init_app")),
                fluidRow("App")
              ))

# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Global.R` according to [shiny docu](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)

I use it to define custom functions and load data to be used in `ui.R` **and** `server.R`

Comment: Thanks! I edit the question. The issue that I have to run code in "setting.R" depending on the "app_id" value that defined on server side.